# Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap RuntimeException on Android 2.3

Tags: android, bitmap, lru

I built a custom view (similar to a grid view) that displays many many many images so recycling Bitmaps is a necessity for this application. I am using an Lru cache (implemented below) to handle the Bitmap recycling. When I tested this on an Android 2.3 device (and scrolling rapidly) I got the following error message and the app crashed. After figuring out how to replicate the bug, I tested it on an Android 4.0 and it worked just fine.

```
06-27 10:57:48.420: E/AndroidRuntime(14255): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 10:57:48.420: E/AndroidRuntime(14255): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@407fc6b8
06-27 10:57:48.420: E/AndroidRuntime(14255):    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:955)
06-27 10:57:48.420: E/AndroidRuntime(14255):    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1044)
06-27 10:57:48.420: E/AndroidRuntime(14255):    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:325)
06-27 10:57:48.420: E/AndroidRuntime(14255):    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:872)
etc etc
```

I tracked this bug around and it turns out that I check if a Bitmap is recycled BEFORE setting the bitmap to an ImageView. However, the Bitmap gets recycled between that step and the draw() step, causing the error.

Here is my cache:

```
 sLruCache =    new LinkedHashMap(capacity / 2, 0.75f, true) {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = -7282875042976381535L;

      @Override
      protected boolean removeEldestEntry(LinkedHashMap.Entry eldest) {
        if (size() > mCapacity) {
          return true;
        } else
          return false;
      }

      public Bitmap remove(Object key) {
        Bitmap bitmap = super.remove(key);
        if (bitmap != NULL_BITMAP) {
          bitmap.recycle();
        }
        return bitmap;
      };

      @Override
      public void clear() { 
        Set keys = new HashSet(keySet());
        for (String key : keys) {
          Bitmap map = get(key);
          if (map != NULL_BITMAP) {
            map.recycle();
          }
        }
        super.clear();
      }
    };
```

Any ideas on why this would fail on Android 2.3 and not 4.0?

Comment: `bitmap.recycle()` you are using a recycled bitmap.

Comment: that's only when it's being removed from the cache. I believe bitmap.recycle() should be used in a remove method. Also, why would this work on Android 4.0?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html. it will work on 4.0 coz there is a change in the way memory is allocated for bitmaps in android 3.0 and above

Comment: When should I recycle them then if not in the remove method? I would run out of memory otherwise

Comment: you should recycle bitmap when it is no longer required and you cannot use the recycled bitmap.

Comment: But that's what I thought I was doing by recycling them in an Lru cache. How do I know if it's no longer required otherwise?

Comment: i am not sure coz i don't know what you are doing. this is all i can do to help

Comment: Just ensure that you do not hold unnecessary references to the bitmap and let the GC do its job

Comment: Agree with @MichaelButscher. Never call `bitmap.recycle()`. Collector will do a good job for you. When you remove bitmap from the `LruCache` doesn't mean the bitmap is not used anywhere. It can be attached to some `View`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

And I had to remove all Bitmap.recycle() calls. It caused OutOfMemoryException sometimes.

Thus, I make a hack like this:

```
// when I need to remove bitmap from cache
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9 || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {
    bmp.recycle();
}
```

It is not a good solution, but It may be helpful.